# Dimension of the space of discrete harmonic functions $f:\mathbb Z^n\to \mathbb R$

Tags: probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, random-walk, harmonic-functions

> Fix $n\in \mathbb N$. Let $F(n)$ be the space of discrete harmonic functions $f:\mathbb Z^n\to \mathbb R$. What is the minimal $d \in \mathbb N$ (if there is one) such that there exists $B\subset F(n)$ with $|B|=d$ that every $f\in F(n)$ can be written as a linear combination of functions from $B$ "subject to a translation", i.e. there is $m\in \mathbb N$ and $(a^1,f^1,x^1),\ldots,(a^m,f^m,x^m) \in \mathbb R \times B \times \mathbb Z^n$ such that $$f(x) = \sum_{j=1}^m a^j f^m(x-x^m) \quad \forall x\in \mathbb Z^n. \tag{*}$$

A function $f:\mathbb Z^n\to \mathbb R$ is harmonic iff
$$
  2nf(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n [f(x-e_i)+f(x+e_i)],
$$
for all $x\in \mathbb Z^n$,
where $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ is the canonical basis of $\mathbb Z^n$. Note that $f$ being discrete harmonic can be interpreted as that $f$ is a martingale w.r.t. a symmetric random walk on $\mathbb Z^n$.

**Case $n=1$:** It is easy to see that $f(x)$ has to have a constant growth, thus $F(1)$ is the space of all the linear functions $f:\mathbb Z\to \mathbb R$.

**Case $n=2$:** Analogously, $F(2)$ also contains all the linear functions $f:\mathbb Z^2\to \mathbb R$. However, the function $f^2_{12}(x) = (x_1)^2 - (x_2)^2$ is also discrete harmonic.  Does $f^2_{12}$ together with the basis of the space of linear functions $f:\mathbb Z^2\to \mathbb R$ span the whole $F(2)$? Clearly not, as @NeitherNor pointed out, there are other linearly independent functions in $F(2)$ and as @RyszardSzwarc brought up, their translations are also in $F(2)$, thus the complicated definition of "basis" $B$.

**Case $n\geq 3$:** Besides the linear functions also the functions $f^3_{ij}=(x_i)^2 - (x_j^2), i\neq j, \ i,j \in \{1,2,3\}$ are harmonic...

Comment: Case $n=2$: also $x_1x_2$ and $x_1x_2(x_1^2-x_2^2)$ are discrete harmonic. Indeed, there are many more I forgot, but: for all $k>0$, there are 2 linearly independent polynomial harmonic functions of order $k$. Anyways, this doesn't mean that there are no non-polynomial ones additionally...

Comment: If $\sum_{i=1}^n z_i+z_i^{-1} = 2n$ then $f(x)= \prod_{i=1}^n z_i^{x_i}$ is solution

Comment: @reuns Won’t this imply that $z_i=1$ for all $i$?

Comment: Let $n=2$. Choose $z_2=0$. Then,  $z_1^2-4z_1+1=0$, which implies $z_1=2\pm\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: For $n=2$: Another possibility to think about it: consider you know the values of an harmonic function inside an Aztec diamond of order $N$ (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aztec_diamond ). Will you be able to uniquely extend it to a corresponding diamond of order $N+1$? The answer is no; instead, you can choose an arbitrary value on each diagonal you extend the diamond, the rest of the harmonic function is then fixed. This gives you that $d=\text{#diagonals}$ (maybe -1 or -2, small Aztec  may behave strange, would have to think about that...). Try it out starting with a  of order $N=1$.

Comment: When $f(x)$ is a solution so is $f(x+k)$ for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}^n.$

Comment: @NeitherNor I thought that $z_2=0$ is not an option as $z_2^{-1}$ is not defined then.

Comment: @NeitherNor I can't see the connection to the Aztec diamond of order $N$, I'll be glad to read your argument with more details.

Comment: I edited the question to make the dimension meaningful even after taking into account @RyszardSzwarc point. (Any suggestions to make the definition simpler? Is there any term for "spanning the space subject to translations"?) I hope that the complicated definition did not make the question less attractive.

Comment: @NeitherNor In the  example of reuns you cannot take $z_2=0,$ as then $f(z)$ is not well defined. Instead you can take $z_2=-1.$

Comment: For $n=2$, the answer to your modified question, now allowing for translations of the "basis vectors" is $d=2$. They are just rotated versions of each other (by 90°), so I will only describe one element in $B$: Set all elements below a given diagonal to zero. Set the elements on the diagonal alternating to 1 and -1. Now, on the next diagonal, set one value to 0, which fixes all others. Continue for the next ones. Compare this construction to my previous comment about Aztec .

Comment: Aztec diamonds are only the simplest diamond shaped domains. Say you know the values of a harmonic function $f$ on a finite convex domain $\Gamma$ of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ (try a 6x6 square domain with $f=0$ inside). Note that, if you know $f$ for a vertex and 3 of its neighbour's, you know $f$ for the fourth neighbor since $\Delta f=0$. This allows you to uniquely iterative extend $f$ to a "-shaped" domain (all boundaries are diagonals). After this, you cannot uniquely extend $f$, resp. have to fix an arbitrary value at each of its outer boundaries to do so. These fixed values c. to degrees

Comment: @NeitherNor This is probably a trivial question – is there a way to see that $x_1x_2(x_1^2-x_2^2)$ is harmonic? All I could do was to verify it by substituting into the condition (*).

Comment: I would plug it into $\Delta x=0$, but otherwise I agree. I think the easiest way would be to start from one of the proposed bases of harmonic functions (all $d=\infty$, most are rather similar) and show that it is in the span (this specific function is typically one of the basis functions itself, so that one is especially easy). In case you are interested in such bases, I would propose asking a new question and linking it here, this question already got changed once...

Comment: Thanks for your answer @NeitherNor. I would definitely not edit the question again given that Ryszard already has provided an answer. I tried to formulate the question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4613232/how-to-generate-all-the-discrete-harmonic-functions-f-mathbb-zn-to-mathbb-r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is : the dimension $d$ is infinite for $n\ge 2.$

At the beginning I will put the problem into a more general framework of finitely generated groups, although it will not help solving it. Let $G=\mathbb{Z}^n.$ The group is generated by $e_1,e_2,\ldots, e_n.$ The generators lead to a natural distance on $G$
$$\|x\|=|x_1|+|x_2|+\ldots +|x_n|$$   Consider the operator acting on functions defined on $G$ by
$$(Af)(x)={1\over 2n}\sum_{j=1}^n[f(x-e_j)+f(x+e_j)]={1\over 2n}\sum_{\|y\|=1} f(x+y)$$
Observe that $A$ is a convolution operator on the group $G$ with the function $$\varphi={1\over 2n}\sum_{j=1}^n[\delta_{e_j}+\delta_{-e_j}]={1\over 2n}\sum_{\|y\|=1}\delta_y$$
i.e. the normalized indicator function of elements with norm $1.$

Concerning the problem, we want to determine the dimension of the eigenspace of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $1,$ i.e. $Af=f.$  We do not impose any norm conditions on $f.$ Some solutions are multiplicative (called usually the characters of the group, if $|f|=1$).
Namely if $f(a+b)=f(a)f(b)$ then
$$f(x)=(Af)(x)={1\over 2n}\sum_{j=1}^n[f(x)f(e_j)+f(x)f(e_j)^{-1}]\\ =
{1\over 2n}\sum_{j=1}^n [f(e_j)+f(e_j)^{-1}]\,f(x)$$
This provides a solution (found by @reuns)
$${1\over 2n}\sum_{j=1}^n[z_j+z_j^{-1}]=1,\quad z_j:=f(e_j)$$

We are going to show that the dimension of harmonic functions is infinite.
Consider $n=2.$ For $z>1 $ let $f_z$ denote the function corresponding to $z_2=-z$ and $z_1>1,$ i.e.
$$z_1=2+{1\over 2}(z+z^{-1})+\sqrt{[2+\textstyle{1\over 2}(z+z^{-1})]^2-1}\ge 1+(z+z^{-1})>z=|z_2|$$
Observe that for $w>z>1 $ we have
$w_1>z_1>1.$ Let $z(k)>z(k-1)>\ldots >z(1)>1.$ We claim that the functions $f_{z(j)}$ are linearly independent.  The corresponding parameters   are $z_1(j)$ and $z_2(j).$ Assume $$a_1f_{z(1)}+a_2f_{z(2)}+\ldots +a_kf_{z(k)}=0$$ With no loss of generality we may assume $a_k\neq 0.$ Substituting $x=je_1$ gives
$$a_1z_1(1)^j+a_2z_1(2)^j+\ldots +a_kz_1(k)^j=0$$
The left hand side is equal asymptotically to $a_kz_1(k)^j$ when $j\to \infty.$ The translation is irrelevant as the translation of $f_z$ is a multiple of $f_z.$ Therefore $a_k=0,$ a contradiction.
The proof is made for $n=2,$ but it can be adapted to any $n\ge 2.$

Comment: Thank you a lot a very well explained solution, I learned a lot by reading it!

Comment: That makes me wonder – is there infinitely many solutions that are neither multiplicative nor a product of a multilicative solution with some more elementary solution, i.e $x_1x_2(x_1^2-x_1^2)$ won't count, but $x_1^2-x_1^2$ would.

Comment: I am glad you liked the answer. Any nontrivial linear combination of multiplicative solutions is a solution, or you are after something else.

Comment: I had in mind a solution in terms of elements of the "bases" $B$, sorry for being vague.